# Re-subscribing to an Observable after error

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I feel like I'm beginning to get the hang of RxSwift - however I've just hit a roadblock. 
Here's an object I've built for a demo (I've simplified it before posting to SO). My issue is, when there's a network error during the upload process, all of the subscriptions get disposed of. So when I tap the `rightBarButtonItem` again, nothing happens.

What's the correct/better way of modelling this? I'm not sure I've grasped the use of `PublishSubject`s correctly!

```
let activityIndicator = ActivityIndicator()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let rx_upload = PublishSubject<Void>()
let rx_progress = PublishSubject<RxProgress>()
let rx_uploadComplete = PublishSubject<Look>()

override init() {
    super.init()

    activityIndicator
        .drive(UIApplication.sharedApplication().rx_networkActivityIndicatorVisible)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    let upload = rx_upload
        .debug("Upload")
        .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] -> Observable<(JSON?, RxProgress)> in
            return self.upload()
        }
        .share()

    upload
        .map { $0.1 }
        .debug("Upload Progress")
        .bindTo(rx_progress)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    upload
        .filter { $0.0 != nil }
        .map { Post(jsonData: $0.0!) }
        .filterNil()
        .debug("Upload Complete")
        .bindTo(rx_uploadComplete)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

}

func upload() -> Observable<(JSON?, RxProgress)> {
    // ...
}
```

And in `ViewController.swift`...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.rx_tap
.bindTo(postUploader.rx_upload)
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 options here:

1. Prevent observables being disposed because of `Error` events.
   You can do this by using `catchError` family.
2. Re-subscribe immediately by using `retry` family.

Base on the way you write your code, I assume that no sample code is needed :D

However, be careful that if an `Subject` receives `Error` or `Completed` events, it will no longer send out any further events.